# java ORM to save in file instead of database

Tags: java, orm

Im looking for a java **ORM** to save the objects into a file ( like serializing it ) and retrieving it from the file instead of using a database (like what hibernate does).

what is a good **ORM** i can use for such a purpose ?

Comment: "best" seeking questions are considered subjective at SO, so someone may come along and downvote it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out that there is no way to do this unless i use the serializers like jackson and Gson and ... and write the whole things on my own .
so what i did was to create a file and save the first 1000 Bytes from the start of it for a binary Tree ( or any other data structure for saving your Meta Data ) which holds the line number of the object and the length of it's serialized String ( kind of like what real databases does ).
so when i wanted to add an object to database i simply would have serialize it and save its Meta Data ( length and line number ) in that tree and then write it to the file .
and when i wanted to retrieve that object back again i just have to read that first 1000 Bytes (the Binary Tree) and see where should i read from the file and simply deserialize that line back to my Object .

simple enough .

Answer (score 1):

You could use json, jaxb, xstream to solve this

Each of this frameworks serialize to xml or json and are able to load your objects again.

Please have a look on the corespondent project website for more information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: its not exactly what ORM's do .json and others that you mentioned , they just serializing and deserializing the objects. but what i want is something like hibernate to be able to save the object into the files . and be able to retrieve them just like hibernate .

Comment: Indeed, what kind of features do you miss?

Comment: retrieving serialized objects is not gonna be easy this way . while in hibernate or other ORM that uses databases you can retrieve the object from database with just giving its name .